# Launching a WebApi application from a Windows App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows

I have a simple WebApi2 app that handles various REST requests. It's essentially a front end for various CRUD operations on an SQL Server Database. Up until now, I've never run it from outside of Visual Studio yet though and I usually don't do Windows specific stuff, but here I am.

My goal is to build this webapp's functionality into a Windows Desktop application (or at least be able to control the webapp from the windows program), mostly so the user can start the Webapp, stop it, see who is connecting to it, etc, but I've got no idea how to go about connecting this particular set of dots. It's actually a pretty tough thing to google.

The WebApp part also needs to be told some things at startup (just strings, so if the answer(s) involve executing various system command lines to tell the WebApp to start/stop/etc and I can pass in what I need on a command line somehow, that's fine).

Ultimately, the goal is to hand the user an install program and he doesn't have to know there is a webserver involved unless he really wants to.

So how would I go about accomplishing this part? (If this question is too vague, tell me why and I'll modify it as necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the good things about Web API is the ability to be hosted outside of a web server such as IIS. For example you could host it inside your Windows Forms application. Here's an [`article with detailed instructions`](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) on how to achieve this.

You would have a `Startup` class that will be used for bootstrapping:

```
public class Startup 
{ 
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
    { 
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "DefaultApi", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
        ); 

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
    } 
}
```

and then its just a matter of starting the listener:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Web Server is running.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will make available your Web API on port 8080 locally and your application can send HTTP requests to it.

So basically the keywords that you are looking for are: `self hosting asp.net web api`.